# How can I set YUV420p byte array as source in MediaPlayerElement of WinUI3

Tags: c#, yuv, winui-3

Exactly what the title says - I am receiving raw YUV byte arrays (in planar YUV4:2:0 format) which I want to set as a source in MediaPlayerElement for my WinUI3 application. Since this is a real-time video feed, I want to avoid delay in rendering as much as possible. What is the best (and fastest) way to do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A MediaPlayerElement accepts lots of possible input ("MediaSource" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource). Among these outputs is IMFMediaSource (Media Foundation) and you can write a custom media source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source (note: it's possible with C# and interop code, but easier with C++). There's a sample here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/general/SimpleMediaSource

Answer (score 0):

You can't, `MediaPlayerElement` handles rendering real video files (avi, mp4, mkv, etc). What you have is raw frame data.

You have many options, the one I personally went with (albeit not for winui3) is using OpenGL to stream the three data channels as textures and decode them in a fragment shader to RGB colors.

For WinUI3 specifically, you have a couple of options if you care about efficiency (as you should for video rendering):

- Similarly to my approach, there's the [`SwapChainPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) class that gives you a DX11 object you can render with. You can then implement exactly what I described above.
- You can also use a [`WriteableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) approach, but you'll have to decode the streams to RGB on the CPU yourself first. Less efficient, but easier to implement.